# Matplotlib plot disappears after annotating?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
    fig1 = figure()
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on = False)
    ax.plot(data[:,0]*1E6, data[:,3]
    ,data[:,0]*1E6, data[:,4],'r')
    plt.xlabel('Time (us)')
    plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
    plt.title('Time')
    plt.grid()
    ax.annotate('axes center', xy=(.5, .5),  xycoords='axes fraction',
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))
    plt.savefig('Time.png',orientation='landscape', pad_inches=0.1)
    plt.clf()
```

The plot disappears after annotating. Only thing that is left after saving is the annotation. Can someone give a suggestion how to save it after annotating.

Comment: Without posting sample data I can't test this.  My suspicion is that multiplying your data vector by 1e6 is making it not visible.

Comment: could you post the few first rows of `data`, so we can reproduce your problem?